# Checking whether user has input a number or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a simple script which finds the Square root of a number. The user inputs a number and it finds the square root and shows the result. I want it to check whether the input was a number or not. If it was a number it'll continue else it'll show a message, and reset.

I tried using:

```
while num != int(x):
    print "That is not a valid number"
    return self.page()
```

But that only shows an error.
Can someone help me out on this?

Here is the code:

```
import math
import sys

class SqRoot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SqRoot, self).__init__()

        self.page()

    def page(self):
        z = 'Enter a number to find its square root: '
        num = int(raw_input(z))
        sqroot = math.sqrt(num)
        print 'The square root of \'%s\' is \'%s\'' % (num, sqroot)
        choose = raw_input('To use again press Y, to quit Press N: ')
        if choose == 'Y' or choose == 'y':
            return self.page()
        elif choose == 'N' or choose == 'n':
            sys.exit(0)

print "SqRoot Finder v1.0"
print "Copyright(c) 2013 - Ahnaf Tahmid"
print "For non-commercial uses only."
print "--------------------------------"

def main():
    app = SqRoot()
    app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to accept only integers, or eventually do you want the user to be able to pass in floating point numbers as well?

Comment: As a side note:  `app()` is invalid in this context as your class doesn't define `__call__`, although there's really no reason for these to be classes in the first place.

Comment: The `int()` function return an integer of whatever is inside the parentheses, so you could convert the string '123' into the integer value 123. The function you probably meant to use is `type()` which returns 'int' for integers and so on, but as other answers have mentioned, this is not a good way to check for a number.

Comment: @ mgilson: I want them to pass in either a floating point number or an integer, depends on them.

Comment: @HelloUni: Is it acceptable if you treat integers as floating point numbers, or do you want to keep track of which one they entered and do different code based on it? (From your code, presumably the former, because `math.sqrt()` will immediately convert an `int` to a `float` anyway… but it's worth thinking things through and actually having the answer before you write the code.)

Comment: @ abarnert: Yes. Integers can be treated as floating points here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the python principles is [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false.

```
x = raw_input('Number?')
try:
    x = float(x)
except ValueError:
    print "This doesn't look like a number!"
```

Comment: `complex` are numbers too ;-), but you probably don't want to use `math.sqrt` on one of those ...

Comment: @mgilson: and so are quaternions and p-adic and whatever else one can come up with...

Comment: @thg45 -- But they're not built-in python types :)

Comment: @mgilson: speaking seriously, you're making a very valid point. Too many beginner and even intermediate programmers tend to use intuitive non-strict definitions for simple objects like "number", "character", "word" etc. and ignore endless complexity behind them.

Comment: @thg435: Well, as of 2.6/3.1, Python has an [actual definition of "number"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) that's what you want in many cases. But of course when that _isn't_ (e.g., sometimes what you really want is "something `numpy` can operate on natively), you have to specify what you mean, so your point is still important. At any rate, this is the right structure for the answer; once the OP defines what he means by "number", he just has to change one line in the (hopefully obvious) way, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the ask forgiveness method, here is a simple function which should work on any valid float number.

```
def isnumber(s):
    numberchars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    dotcount=0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if (i==0 and s[i]=='-'):
            pass
        elif s[i]=='.' and dotcount==0:
            dotcount+=1
        elif s[i] not in numberchars:
            return False
    return True
```

Note:  You can add base 16 easy by changing numberchars to:

```
numberchars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
```